# Spring 4 + Apache Tiles 3 display plain text

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, tiles, apache-tiles

I'm going to setup a new project with Spring 4 and Apache Tiles 3. I have a weird problem.

When my tiles definition is loaded, instead to display the requested JSP, the controller returns to the browser the plain text not rendered.

**view.xml**

```
<bean id="tilesViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer" id="tilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles/tiles-definitions.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**tiles-definition.xml**

```
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="welcome" template="/WEB-INF/view/jsp/template.jsp" >
        <put-attribute name="header" value="Test" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="Test" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="Test" />
    </definition>
```

**template.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles" %>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header"><tiles:insertAttribute name="header"/></div>
        <div id="body"><tiles:insertAttribute name="body"/></div>
        <div id="footer"><tiles:insertAttribute name="footer"/></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Spring log on request**

```
17:23:55.637 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'applicationServlet' processing GET request for [/eurostart/]
17:23:55.637 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /
17:23:55.637 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Returning handler method [public java.lang.String it.insiel.eurostart.controller.WelcomeController.home()]
17:23:55.638 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'welcomeController'
17:23:55.638 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Last-Modified value for [/eurostart/] is: -1
17:23:55.639 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView: name 'welcome'; URL [welcome]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'applicationServlet'
17:23:55.639 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.a.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer - Render request received for definition 'welcome'
17:23:55.640 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'applicationServlet' processing GET request for [/eurostart/WEB-INF/view/jsp/template.jsp]
17:23:55.640 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /WEB-INF/view/jsp/template.jsp
17:23:55.640 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/WEB-INF/view/jsp/template.jsp]
17:23:55.641 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Matching patterns for request [/WEB-INF/view/jsp/template.jsp] are [/**]
17:23:55.641 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - URI Template variables for request [/WEB-INF/view/jsp/template.jsp] are {}
17:23:55.641 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapping [/WEB-INF/view/jsp/template.jsp] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler@5f37e070] and 1 interceptor
17:23:55.641 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Last-Modified value for [/eurostart/WEB-INF/view/jsp/template.jsp] is: -1
17:23:55.642 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'applicationServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
17:23:55.642 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
17:23:55.643 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
```

Thank to all who will help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a big wrong in **web.xml** mapping the application servlet with /* instead of /

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>applicationServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to include tilesConfigurer bean in your view.xml file:

```
    <bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer" >
        <property name="definitions">
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles/tiles-definitions.xml</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

try to configure view resolver bean like:

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass">
            <value>
                org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView
            </value>
    </property>
</bean>
  <!-- The actual tiles templates are in the tiles-definitions.xml  -->         
<bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer"> 
    <property name="definitions">       
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles/tiles-definitions.xml</value>
        </list>     
    </property> 
</bean>
```

and **tiles-definition.xml**

```
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="base.definition"
          template="/WEB-INF/view/jsp/layout.jsp">
      <put-attribute name="title" value="" />
      <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/view/jsp/template/header.jsp" />

      <put-attribute name="body" value="" />
      <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/view/jsp/template/footer.jsp" />
    </definition>
    <definition name="welcome" extends="base.definition">
      <put-attribute name="title" value="Home" />
      <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/view/jsp/welcome.jsp" />
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

Then, from your Controller return tiles definition name.

Like:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String welcome(){
  return "welcome"; //tiles definition name
}
```